# google colab import imagemagick PolicyError: not authorized `file.pdf'

Tags: python, pdf, imagemagick, google-colaboratory

used google colab. had to install imagemagick as a dependency for pdfplumber lib to work.

```
!apt install imagemagick
```

also

```
!pip install pdfplumber
```

then my code looked like this -

```
pdf = pdfplumber.open("file.pdf") # Import the PDF.
page = pdf.pages[0] 
im = page.to_image()
im
```

when running this piece of code got this error -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PolicyError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-61f21a06c7de> in <module>
---> 14 im = page.to_image()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wand/resource.py in raise_exception(self, stacklevel)
    223             warnings.warn(e, stacklevel=stacklevel + 1)
    224         elif isinstance(e, Exception):
--> 225             raise e
    226 
    227     def make_blob(self, format=None):

PolicyError: not authorized `file.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412
```

Answer (score 1):

found this [answer](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/issues/81#issuecomment-1312277946) helpful (with the help of pdfplumber team)

going into etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

Had to change this:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF"/>
```

to this:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF"/>
```

then ran again and the photo appeared. Solved it for me :)